# Android how to rotate a photo depending on orientation when picture is taken custom camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-orientation, android-framelayout

I am stuck at a point that I cannot change orientation of picture when I have taken the picture using custom camera. I want to manually handle the orientation. I dont know how to rotate a picture in onConfigurationchanged when Camera.PictureCallback is called. I have successfully changed the orientation when photo is not taken.I am not setting image in any image view instead I am showing it in surface view. Here is my code of setting framelayout and surface for it:

```
Framelayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
CameraSurfaceCreater mCameraView = new CameraSurfaceCreater(this, mCamera, CameraSetter.this);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
```

when picture is taken:

```
   Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

              pictaken = true;
            }
};
```

and in onConfiguration Changed:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            if(!isPictureTaken){
                setCameraDisplayOrientation(CameraSetter.this, 0, mCamera);
            }else {
               //dont know how to rotate a photo when picture is taken
            }

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if(!isPictureTaken){
                setCameraDisplayOrientation(CameraSetter.this, 0, mCamera);
            }

        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Do I have to rotate framelayout or what I have to do after photo is taken and user changes the orientation.

Answer (score 1):

**Make use of OrientationEventListener as follow:**

```
OrientationEventListener mOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(mApplication,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

            if ((orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) || (mCamera == null)) {
                return;
            }

            Log.e("current_ori", "" + orientation);

            Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();

            Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

            orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;

            int rotation = 0;

            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {

                //Below one line will rotate image to portrait
                // rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;

                //Below code makes image exactly how it has been captured(with mirror)

                if (orientation == 360 || orientation == 0 || orientation == 180) {
                    rotation = 270;
                } else if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
                    rotation = 90;
                }

            } else {
                /*
                 * back-facing camera
                 */
                //Below one line will rotate image to portrait
                //rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;

                //Below line makes image exactly how it has been captured
                rotation = 90;

            }

            params.setRotation(rotation);

            if (null == mCamera) {
                return;
            }

            mCamera.setParameters(params);
        }
    };
```

Don't forget to enable and disable OrientationEventListener:

**To Enable:**

```
if (mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        mOrientationEventListener.enable();
    }
```

**To Disable:**

```
if (mOrientationEventListener.canDetectOrientation()) {
        mOrientationEventListener.disable();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but where should I add this OrientationEventListener in code? or should I remove onconfigurationchanged?

Comment: you can add this code in your onCreate() but make sure you use this after the camera has initialized. Enable this from onResume() and Disable from onPause().

Comment: This has a problem that when ever you take a picture and device is moved to landscape picture is removed and it turns on the camera again.

Comment: Are you showing the taken picture in the same activity?

Comment: Instead of rotating the picture it turns on the camera and camera is rotated

Comment: Yes in same activity.I am adding surface view in the frame layout which shows the picture. I am not showing it in image view.

Comment: Whenever the orientation gets to change your activity will start once again. So that onCreate() will call once again.

Comment: To stop that behaviour I have added this in manifest so only onConfigurationChanged is called:             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

Comment: after adding that android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize‌​"  on create will not be called again only onConfigChanged will be called